# Rails Polymorphic Nested Attribute with fields_for unable to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I have the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile_image, :as => :owner, :class_name => 'Image'
  has_one :cover_image,   :as => :owner, :class_name => 'Image'
end
```

and:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now I am trying to build a form where a user can update his/her images, and his/her e-mail. I am building the form like this:

```
= form_for @user, :url => pages_upload_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form|
  = form.text_field :email
  = form.fields_for :profile_image_attributes do |profile_image|
    = profile_image.file_field :file
  = form.fields_for :cover_image_attributes do |cover_image|
    = cover_image.file_field :file
  = submit_tag("Upload")
```

This however compiles to the following params hash:

```
[2] pry(#<PagesController>)> params[:user]
=> {"email"=>"kasper@example.com",
 "profile_image"=>
  {"file"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8a41365d30
     @content_type="image/png",
     @headers=
      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_image][file]\"; filename=\"Screenshot 2014-04-27 02.57.34.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
     @original_filename="Screenshot 2014-04-27 02.57.34.png",
     @tempfile=
      #<File:/var/folders/_2/rgn574910638hqstf85233hh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140518-88429-15129ld>>},
 "cover_image"=>
  {"file"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8a413653d0
     @content_type="image/png",
     @headers=
      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[cover_image][file]\"; filename=\"Screenshot 2014-04-27 02.57.34.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
     @original_filename="Screenshot 2014-04-27 02.57.34.png",
     @tempfile=
      #<File:/var/folders/_2/rgn574910638hqstf85233hh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140518-88429-1oosnc5>>}}
```

But when I save this, like this, I get the following error:

```
@user = User.last
@user.update_attributes(params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:email, :profile_image => [:file]))
# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Image(#70115863220300) expected, got    
# ActionController::Parameters(#70115879244320)
# from /Users/kaspergrubbe/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems
# /activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:216:in
# `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
```

How can I get it to accept my attributes for the `profile_image`?

Comment: Removing the `:class_name =>'Image'` could solve the problem i guess.

Comment: Post the `controller code` please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile_image
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cover_image
```

The error you're getting is a result of the way rails assigns attributes. For each key it calls `#{key}=` method, so in your case it is trying assign hash to `profile_image`.

When you add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` many thing will change. Firstly, it will define `profile_image_attributes=` method which expects Hash object which will be used to build or update associated object. When `fields_for` noticed that this method is defined, it will update name of the field to contain `_attributes` at the end, so everything will work.

Note however that fields_for will not build if there is no object associated, so you will need to build those objects in your new and edit action.

Comment: LOL :D Why didn't i see it before.